How to charge for grace period and charge for previous month unpaid amount in stripe
In our saas application we have business($30) and enterprise plan($60).
If jan 1 user subscribed to enterprise plan, by jan end the subscrution will end. So feb if they did'nt pay we will give them the plan they alread in without paying.
So when they come back to pay for subscription example feb 15 thier billing period end at feb end and we need to charge them according to below cases
How to aheive below cases:

If the user chooses to continue with the previous enterprise plan:

Charge the user the full amount of the enterprise plan ($60). Set the
billing period to end at the end of the current month (February).


If the user chooses to downgrade to the business plan in feb itself:

Charge the user for the remaining days of the enterprise plan for the current month (February).

Calculate the prorated amount for the remaining days of the enterprise plan and charge accordingly.

Set the billing period to end at the end of the current month (February) for the business plan.



If the user didn't pay in February and pays on March 1st:

Charge the user for the entire month of February (if they haven't paid for it yet) and the entire month of March.



Thanks in advance.

Welcome to [so]. Please read How To Ask a Good Question. "please help me" is not a question; we don't write code to specification. You are expected to study the problem ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

If Stripe's Subscription is used, here are the answers to your question.
The subscription doesn't update to any new plan, the existing plan will remain throughout the entire subscription, i.e. if the subscription is created with Enterprise plan, same plan will always remain until any plan change is made on the subscription.


If the user chooses to continue with the previous enterprise plan

For every new billing cycle, Stripe will create an invoice. In Feb, its respective invoice would have been created. Your system should ensure that the customer make payment on this specific invoice.
By default, the new invoice for Enterprise will be created in next cycle automatically. In your case, it'll be Mar 1.
To change the billing cycle of existing subscription, I'd recommend checking the guide here: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#changing


If the user chooses to downgrade to the business plan in feb itself

When downgrading or upgrading a subscription plan using this guide, proration will be calculated by Stripe automatically by default. The list of proration_behavior options can be found here


If the user didn't pay in February and pays on March 1st

New invoice will be created for March. Customer will have to pay both invoices for both February and March.

There is another case. If user is in our grace period of 30 days. Imagine they did not paid for jan so they got a grace period.
But 15th of jan they came they choose another plan called enterprise. So in this case we need to charge 15 days of the prev plan because we given the plan without paying money and 15 days enterprise upto jan.
How to handle this logic ?
